# Difference between using [] and list() in Python

Tags: python, list

Can somebody explain this code ?

```
l3 = [ {'from': 55, 'till': 55, 'interest': 15}, ]
l4 = list( {'from': 55, 'till': 55, 'interest': 15}, )

print l3, type(l3)
print l4, type(l4)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'till': 55, 'from': 55, 'interest': 15}] <type 'list'>
['till', 'from', 'interest'] <type 'list'>
```

Comment: I guess `list` uses dict.keys() and the first one is a list of dicts.

Comment: dict is an iterable (by keys), the `list()` takes an iterable and returns the list.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you convert a `dict` object to a list, it only takes the keys.

However, if you surround it with square brackets, it keeps everything the same, it just makes it a list of `dict`s, with only one item in it.

```
>>> obj = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8}
>>> list(obj)
[1, 3, 5, 7]
>>> [obj]
[{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8}]
>>>
```

This is because, when you loop over with a `for` loop, it only takes the keys as well:

```
>>> for k in obj:
...     print k
... 
1
3
5
7
>>>
```

But if you want to get the keys **and** the values, use `.items()`:

```
>>> list(obj.items())
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
>>>
```

Using a `for` loop:

```
>>> for k, v in obj.items():
...     print k, v
... 
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
>>>
```

However, when you type in `list.__doc__`, it gives you the same as `[].__doc__`:

```
>>> print list.__doc__
list() -> new list
list(sequence) -> new list initialized from sequence's items
>>> 
>>> print [].__doc__
list() -> new list
list(sequence) -> new list initialized from sequence's items
>>>
```

Kind of misleading :)

Comment: `__doc__` is class(`list`) attribute, no wonder its instances(`[]`) have that too.

Answer (score 7):

- The former just wraps the entire item in square brackets `[]`, making it a one-item list:

  ```
  >>> [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}]
  [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}]
  ```
- The latter iterates over the dictionary (getting keys) and produces a list out of them:

  ```
  >>> list({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
  ['foo', 'bar']
  ```

Comment: One more thing worth to be mentioned: if you want to create only one element in the list. `list()` might cause error such as, `list(3)`. Only [3] can work.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> help(list)

Help on class list in module __builtin__:

class list(object)
 |  list() -> new empty list
 |  list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
```

In the first case the notation indicates you're creating a list with a dictionary as its object. The list is created empty and the dictionary is appended as an object.

In the second case you're calling the second form of the list constructor - "initialized from iterable's items". In a dictionary it's the keys that are iterable, so you get a list of the dictionary keys.

Answer (score 3):

The list is a constructor that will take any basic sequence (so tuples, dictionaries, other lists, etc.) and can turn them into lists. Alternatively, you could make the lists with [] and it will make a list with all the things you put inside the brackets. You can actually accomplish the same things with list comprehension.

```
 13 = [item for item in {'from': 55, 'till': 55, 'interest': 15}]
 14 = list({'from': 55, 'till': 55, 'interest': 15})
```