# Why are [range(10)] and list(range(10)) not the same?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, range

Why are `[range(10)]` and `list(range(10))` different in Python 3?

Output is as follows:

```
>>> print([range(10)])
[range(0, 10)]
>>> print(list(range(10)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I know this has been asked before, but I can't find a dupe target. Google isn't turning up anything relevant.

Comment: @JanHudec Thanks for replying, but can you expand more on what you mean by that?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes I tried to look it up as well and just decided to ask even if I got down votes, since it's better to learn than worry about points

Comment: @ChristianDean: No, that one won't do. That question is about how to construct an empty list or dict, and the answers focus on timing. It doesn't cover the semantics of using `[]` or `list` to create a list with elements.

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703109/difference-between-using-and-list-in-python) looks better, but I think the dict in that question is too distracting for that question to serve as a good []-vs-list dupe target.

Comment: @user2357112 You're right. I wasn't paying attention.. That's a very poor dupe target. I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists), "lists may be constructed in several ways":

```
[range(10)]
```

builds a list of 1 item, the [range object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). In general a comma separated list of items enclosed in square brackets constructs a list of said items.

```
list(range(10))
```

passes the [range object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) as an argument to the [list constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list):

> `class list([iterable])`
>
> The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same order as *iterable‘s* items. *iterable* may be either a sequence, a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If *iterable* is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to `iterable[:]`. For example, `list('abc')` returns `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `list( (1, 2, 3) )` returns `[1, 2, 3]`. If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list, `[]`.

A range in Python 3 [represents an immutable sequence of numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range), so in your case the resulting list is a list of numbers from the range.

Answer (score 5):

`[x]` means "make a list whose one element is `x`".

`list(x)` means "make a list whose elements are the *elements of* `x`".

`range(10)` returns an object that prints as `range(0, 10)` (since it shows the starting value when it prints) and whose elements are the integers from 0 to 9, so `[range(10)]` gives the one-element list `[range(0, 10)]` and `list(range(10))` gives the 10-element list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you are simply creating a list object using square bracket notation, and placing a `range()` object inside. On the other hand, in your second example, you use the `list()` builtin to *convert* the `range()` object to a list.

The difference, is that using `[]` simply creates a list. It does nothing to the contents passed in. `list()` on the other hand, will either return an empty list if you pass nothing in, or attempt to convert what you passed in to a list object.

[The documentation for `list()` notes this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list):

> The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable‘s items. iterable may be either a sequence, a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to iterable[:]. For example, list('abc') returns ['a', 'b', 'c'] and list( (1, 2, 3) ) returns [1, 2, 3]. If no argument is given, the constructor creates a new empty list, [].

Answer (score 0):

`range()` function in python 3.x is similar to the `xrange()` function in python 2.x.In Python 2.x `range()` produced a list, and `xrange()` returned an iterator - a sequence object

**In python 2.x**

```
>>> range(1)
[0]
>>> type(range(1))
<type 'list'>
```

**In python 3.x**

```
>>> range(1)
range(0, 1)
>>> type(range(1))
<class 'range'>
```

And to get a list, you can pass the generator in `list()`

```
>>> print (list(range(10)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

For further reference , read [here](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)